# nvd3.js how to show yAxis tickFormat in currency

Tags: nvd3.js

I am plotting bar (discrete chart) using **nvd3.js.**

Currently, I am using following line to show y-axis ticks

```
chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));
```

However, i need to change it to show yAxis tickFormat in currency format.

Is there any built in (defined character) to show in currency format? If no than how i can show yAxis in currency format?

Please advise. Let me know if you know more details.

After googling , i found the way to do it.

```
            var commasFormatter = d3.format(",");

            chart.yAxis
              .tickFormat(function(d) { return "$" + commasFormatter(d); });
```

**But another question, i need to append USD with the currency value. How i can do that?** e.g. 1,200 USD

Comment: Got it working using ".tickFormat(function(d) { return "$" + commasFormatter(d) + " USD"; });"

Comment: Is there any other better way?

Comment: No, this is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the same thing you did with "$":

```
chart.yAxis
    .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.format(",")(d) + " USD" });
```